# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop; Check the render method of `Post`

Tags: reactjs

when I click by tag, it works fine, but when I click creators, it just return "No posts".
I check the console, and there's an error says the key in list should be unique. Why this happens? Since searchbytag works, does this mean the render method of 'Post' is fine?
updated code

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000' });

API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('profile')) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer 
${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')).token}`;
  }

  return req;
});
export const createPost = (newPost) => API.post('/posts', newPost);
  const Post = ({ post, setCurrentId }) => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(post?.likes);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const classes = useStyles();

  const userId = user?.result?._id;
  const hasLikedPost = post.likes.find((like) => like === userId);

  const handleLike = async () => {
    dispatch(likePost(post._id));

    if (hasLikedPost) {
      setLikes(post.likes.filter((id) => id !== userId));
    } else {
      setLikes([...post.likes, userId]);
    }
  };

  const Likes = () => {
    if (likes.length > 0) {
      return likes.find((like) => like === userId)
        ? (
          <><ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize="small" />&nbsp;{likes.length > 2 ? `You and ${likes.length - 1} others` : `${likes.length} like${likes.length > 1 ? 's' : ''}`}</>
        ) : (
          <><ThumbUpAltOutlined fontSize="small" />&nbsp;{likes.length} {likes.length === 1 ? 'Like' : 'Likes'}</>
        );
    }

    return <><ThumbUpAltOutlined fontSize="small" />&nbsp;Like</>;
  };

  const openPost = (e) => {
    // dispatch(getPost(post._id, history));

    history.push(`/posts/${post._id}`);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card} raised elevation={6}>
      <ButtonBase
        component="span"
        name="test"
        className={classes.cardAction}
        onClick={openPost}
      >
        <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={post.selectedFile || 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/194400/49531010-48dad180-f8b1-11e8-8d89-1e61320e1d82.png'} title={post.title} />
        <div className={classes.overlay}>
          <Typography variant="h6">{post.name}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2">{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</Typography>
        </div>
        {(user?.result?._id === post?.creator) && (
          <div className={classes.overlay2} name="edit">
            <Button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                setCurrentId(post._id);
              }}
              style={{ color: 'white' }}
              size="small"
            >
              <MoreHorizIcon fontSize="default" />
            </Button>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className={classes.details}>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="h2">{post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag} `)}</Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">{post.title}</Typography>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{post.message.split(' ').splice(0, 20).join(' ')}...</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </ButtonBase>
      <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
        <Button size="small" color="primary" disabled={!user?.result} onClick={handleLike}>
          <Likes />
        </Button>
        {(user?.result?._id === post?.creator) && (
          <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={() => dispatch(deletePost(post._id))}>
            <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" /> &nbsp; Delete
          </Button>
        )}
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

export default Post;

Here's my code

```
const CreatorOrTag = () => {
const { name } = useParams();
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { posts, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  if (location.pathname.startsWith('/creators')) {
    dispatch(getPostsByCreator({ name: name }));
  }
  else {
    dispatch(getPostsBySearch({ tags: name }));
  }
}, []);


 if (!posts.length && !isLoading) return 'No posts';

return (
<div>
  <Typography variant="h2">{name}</Typography>
  <Divider style={{ margin: '20px 0 50px 0' }} />
  {isLoading ? <CircularProgress /> : (
    <Grid container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
      {posts?.map((post) => (
        <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={3}>
          <Post post={post} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  )}
</div>
```

);
};

export default CreatorOrTag;

Comment: As the error says: *Check the render method of `Post`* - which is not in your question

Comment: You are not providing `Post` component code. The obvious asumption is that one or more posts have the same `id`.

Comment: @ivanatias: I checked and think that every post have a unique id ..

Comment: It would be helpful if you include your `Post` code so we can assist you further.

Comment: @ivanatias :is that ok? don't expect it to be too redundant lol..

Comment: I think I noticed where the warning is coming from. In your `Post` component, in one of your `Typography` you are mapping the post tags and not assigning any `key` to it.

Comment: You may want to refactor the way in which you render your tags. You could directly map `post.tags` and for each one create a `Typography`, assigning the tag itself as a `key` (since I assume they're all unique).

Comment: @ivanatias : thanks a lot! tags can be repeated though... but I will follow this direction and try to think of a way, thank you again

Answer (score -1):

What this warning indicates is that the value you're providing for `key` is the same in at least two items of the array. I'd put money on the `_id` property for at least two of them being `null` or `undefined`.